# How do I make form (two inputs) take me to another page which selections depends on the input

Tags: javascript, html, forms, backend

I would greatly appreciate any help as Im unable to solve my problem.
Im grateful for any comment on what tech or backend stuff do i learn for this to work or simply for anything that moves me forward.

Thanks in advance ! 
*PS: Im second grade IT high school student, this is different lvl than we have learned so far and im just keen on solving this form.*

**I managed to do:**

I created a form which is consisted of two text inputs. 
The user would type in **(example)** place1 (place where he beggins) and place2 (place where he wanna go).
It would autocomplete what is he writting and this would be the only valid inputs. 
I prepared Place 1 - Place 5

**I need help with :**

Then it decides which page would be adequate to what the user typed in, for example user typed in Place 1 and Place 5, after he clicks the submit button he is redirected to a site which displays information on what he can visit on his way from Place 1 to Place 5. I dont care about the information he gets, im interested only in how do I create something that redirects the user accordingly on what he typed in.

**The code is in here:**
https://github.com/lukasbryla/FORM-PROBLEM

Many thanks in advance ♥

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty simple if you are using php.  There is an excellent example on [this site](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp), along with other helpful info.

Look into the GET method towards the end of that page, that is probably the simplest for this.

I would suggest that instead of redirecting the user according to their choices, you would have the form send the used to a results page that will have content generated by their choices.

If you can't use PHP, you can do a similar sort of thing with javascript using the GET method.